# jquery date picker locale setting not working in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I try to set locale of datepicker to FR in wordpress in this way

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( '.creation_date' ).datepicker( jQuery.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
    jQuery('.creation_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

But it's no working. 
How сan to set locale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
$('.creation_date').datepicker({
  regional: 'fr',
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

And don't forget to load locale file. For example [this one](https://cdn.rawgit.com/jquery/jquery-ui/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-fr.js) for French.

Full test here: https://jsfiddle.net/eb6w2xdo/